# Tick checkbox and run onclick event by clicking a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, webgl

Below you can see two checkboxes within a table. Ticking a checkbox switches the visbility/highlight state of a WebGL-model.

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="AssemblyTable" style="position: absolute; top: 62px; left: 10px; font-weight: bold; color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
  <thead style="font-size:14px;">
      <tr>
        <th height="30" align="left">&nbsp;</th>
        <th align="left">&nbsp;</th>
        <th align="left">&nbsp;</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody style="font-size:12px;">
    <tr>

        <tr><td><code>&nbsp;&nbsp;</code></td>

        <td><input type="checkbox" id="Sh-Cmp1" onclick="javascript:myAssemblyBrowser.switchVisibilityState('Sh-Cmp1')" checked="true"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="Hl-Cmp1" onclick="javascript:myAssemblyBrowser.switchHighlightState('Hl-Cmp1')" ></td></tr>

    </tbody>

  </table>
```

I need to check the checkbox and execute the function by clicking a link which is not within the table.

I managed to tick the checkbox but the function itself was not executed.

How can I do this? 
I've been messing around with jQuery's toggle-function but for some reason it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

this pure javascript snippet should trigger the click event for the element with id "myLink":

```
document.getElementById('myLink').onclick();
```

no jQuery required in this approach.

hope that helps.

Comment: `code`document.getElementById('myLink').click();`code` worked